# Peer-to-Peer Memory Access throws excetion

Tags: cuda, gpu, thrust

Morning everyone

I want to test p2p memory access when I studying thrust. But there are something wrong.

The test code is like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
using namespace std;

void test(thrust::device_vector<int> &Vec)
{
    try{
    thrust::negate<int> op;
    thrust::transform(Vec.begin(),Vec.end(),Vec.begin(),op);
    }catch(thrust::system::system_error &e)
    {
            cerr<<"Something wrong: "<<e.what()<<endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    cudaSetDevice(0);
    thrust::device_vector<int> Vec(5);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
            Vec[i]=i;
            cout<<i<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    int TID=1;
    cudaSetDevice(TID);
    cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess(0,0);
    test(Vec);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            cout<<Vec[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;  
}
```

I execute this code, and it gives me error message.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'
  what():  invalid device pointer
Aborted
```

What happend to it?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on whether your devices support unified addressing, otherwise you would have to call cudaPeerRegister from GPUdirect first in order to access memory from other GPU.

You can check this using cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer() from your second device.
Also you can call cudaGetDeviceProperties() and check for unifiedAddressing field.

PS. I just checked your code on a machine with 4 Tesla S2050 GPUs 
and for me  cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer() returns 0 and hence direct access does not work..

Comment: I have checked it, returned 1.but there is the same terminate information @asm

Comment: hmm.. can you also check if some Cuda-related error occurs before ?
ie. wrap each call to CUDA runtime functions using a macros like: 
#define CUDA_SAFE_CALL( call) {                                    \
    cudaError err = call;                                                    \
    if( cudaSuccess != err) {                                                \
        fprintf(stderr, "Cuda error in file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n",        \
                __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString( err) );              \
        exit(1);     } }

Comment: Sorry for replying you so late, I use my cellphone to read your answer.  Each Thrust call cannot be warped with CUDA_SAFE_CALL. I use device_malloc instead of device_vector l.

Comment: nope I mean just wrapping up each cuda runtime call, ie.: CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess(..)); or CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaSetDevive(..)); 
to check if maybe some runtime error occurs earlier

Comment: I did it, all cuda call be warped are  ok.

Comment: Maybe the device_vector<int > pointer is not suitable. Maybe vector iterator needs to be transformed to other device pointer.

Comment: you can also place 'cudaSetDevice(0)' at the end of 'main' to see if it still generates the error message. It could be that device_vector calls a destructor which cannot dispose memory allocated on device 0 when device 1 is selected..

Comment: 4.0version. Your solution is alternative

Comment: Thank you so much. Just like you said, add cudaSetDevice(0) before return 0 make this code gives no errors.